# Can't Get ModX Resource ID

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I'm having trouble with the ModX API. I'm trying to grab the resource ID thusly:

```
require_once '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/config.core.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH.'model/modx/modx.class.php';
$modx = new modX();

$data = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET);

$modx->initialize('web');
$modx->getService('error','error.modError', '', '');
$modx->getService('mail', 'mail.modPHPMailer');
$dataObjs = $modx->getObject('modResource', $data['doc']);`
```

The problem is, $data['doc'] always returns 1. So it looks like filter_input_array isn't working. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the $data variable value/content?

Comment: The output of `$test = implode('-',$data);` is 1 regardless of the resource ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the filter_input_array function and without any arguments I am not sure what it is buying you or if it will even work. If the goal is to get the GET key 'doc' and have it sanitized then you can do the following

```
$_get_data = $modx->sanitize($_GET);

$modx->initialize('web');
$modx->getService('error','error.modError', '', '');
$modx->getService('mail', 'mail.modPHPMailer');
$dataObjs = $modx->getObject('modResource', $_get_data['doc']);
```